# Laravel Batch InsertOrUpdate fails

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Is there a way to do batch `DB::table()->updateOrInsert()` for Laravel? When I pass a multi-dimensional array like this:

```php
array(10){
    [1]=>
    array(1){
        ["id"] => int(1)
    }
    [2]=>
    array(1){
        ["id"] => int(2)
    }
    ...
}
```

for my `$key` in the method

```php
array(10){
    [1]=>
    array(2){
        ["id"] => int(1)
        ["name"] => string(3) "Kim"
    }
    [2]=>
    array(2){
        ["id"] => int(2)
        ["name"] => string(3) "Sam"
    }
    ...
}
```

for my `$value`, it spits out `Column not found: 1054 Unknown column '1' in 'where clause'` where `1` is the `id` of the `$key`, since it tries to use the query

```sql
SELECT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE (`1` IS NULL AND `2` IS NULL AND ...) as `exists`) AS EXISTS
```

or are there other ways to do batch UPDATE with matching primary key if it exists and insert the data if it doesn't? Similar to `ON DUPLICATE UPDATE` function for raw MySQL query.

Comment: `updateOrInsert` does not support batch inserts. `insertOrIgnore` does but it's not the same as the `ON DUPLICATE KEY` functionality but rather as  the `INSERT IGNORE` functionality. You might need to execute the raw query

Comment: @apokryfos is right. `insertOrIgnore` will take 1 record and update it according to source code, so if you want to update in batch, you can use `ON DUPLICATE KEY` or `CASE WHEN`